# Counter too large error with \item

Tags: errors, lists

I am a new LaTeX user. I already searched through the topic and I have not found an answer yet. I am using the `exercise` package to build a large Multiple Choice math question set complete with an answer key and full explanations. This is the format of a typical Multiple Choice question:

```
\item \(\frac{19^2+19}{19}\)

\begin{enumerate}[(A)] % (A), (B), (C), (D),(E)

\item   396

\item  361

\item  38

\item  21

\item  20 

\end{enumerate}

\textbf{Explanation}\par

We may simplify the fraction by separating it into two fractions as follows:\par

\(\frac{19^{2}+19}{19}\)=\(\frac{19^2}{19}+\frac{19}{19}=19+1=20\)\par

\textbf{Answer:E}\par
```

**The number of questions has grown beyond 50** and I have started getting the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Counter too large.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.418 \item I
             f $x=\sqrt{5}{-37}$, then which of the following must be true?
?
```

I may be doing something wrong with the `alphalph`  package, so kindly help me resolve this problem. If I were to use the following command, what do I write instead of `\thesection` and `section`.

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\alphalph{\value{section}}}
```

Sorry if this question has already been answered before.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I don't understand why you redefine `\thesection`. The problem is `\theenumi` which is in your case restricted (probably) to the value of 26 at most, unless redefined. Are you using the `enumerate` package?

Comment: Yes, I am using the enumerate package.

Comment: Christian -  Same error again. Just a note that this worked OK for 50 questions, so this error may not be related to \theenumi. Also, I am not looking to change the formatting. \item already gives me a question number  - I am only looking to allow it to continue numbering the questions to 200 or so.

Answer (score 11):

This is a short hack, for `enumerate` package using `\AlphAlph` as counter output format. (The `\foreach` is just the loop to generate 50 `\item` )

In a normal setup, `enumerate[(A)]` can use only the 26 characters of the Latin alphabet such that `\Alph{enumi}` would fail if the `enumi` counter has a value of 27 or greater. To prevent this, the `[(A)]` output must be changed to use `\AlphAlph{\value{enumi}}` (for example)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{alphalph}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{pgffor}


\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\AlphAlph{\value{enumi}}}

\begin{enumerate} 
\foreach \x in {1,...,50} {%
  \item Question \x 
}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Improved version with `enumitem`**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{alphalph}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\AlphAlphFmt}[1]{\@alphfmt{#1}}  % Define the \AlphAlph wrapper for enumitem 
\newcommand{\@alphfmt}[1]{\AlphAlph{\value{#1}}}  % Internal representation 
\AddEnumerateCounter{\AlphAlphFmt}{\@alphfmt}{AAA} % Register this new format
\makeatother

\newlist{mcenum}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[mcenum,1]{label={(\AlphAlphFmt*)}}


\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{mcenum}
\foreach \x in {1,...,60} {%
  \item Question \x 
}
\end{mcenum}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll try a solution with the more flexible `enumitem` package

Comment: Christian - Thanks for the help. I am getting the same error again. Just a note that the existing set up worked OK for 50 questions, so this error may not be related to \theenumi. Also, I am not looking to change the formatting. \item already gives me a question number - I am only looking to allow it to continue numbering the questions to 200 or so.

Comment: @Htown: The formatting is one thing. If you use `Alpha` formatting, you will get troubles. Unless you do not show your setup it's not really possible to provide help. The question number is just for the example here, not for production

Comment: The file is too long - about 700 lines. How do I upload on here for your review?

Comment: @Htown: It would be sufficient if you cut some of the questions -- I can put  easily dummy questions (the questions themselves aren't the problem, it's the way the enumi counter should be typeset)

Comment: May I try emailing the code to you on the address provided on your profile? Or would it be OK to post the code here unformatted?

Comment: @Htown: You mail it to me... I'll stay online for at least one additional hour to find a solution

Comment: Just sent you an email on your profile email address.

Comment: @Htown: Yes, I received it. I'll look into that file right now

Comment: @Htown: You are using nested `enumerates`, i.e. `\begin{enumerate} \item ... \begin{enumerate}`... This might fail. And I've run into too deeply nested enumerates, i.e. it seems that there is some `\end{enumerate}` missing, causing the whole trouble. In order to check this, some questions should be removed and stored back later on

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the missing \end{enumerate} was the problem!

Comment: An unrelated question - Is there a way to automatically store the answer key and explanations in two separate sections toward the end of the document? So, the question set, then the answer key , and then the full explanations

Comment: @Htown: That's a totally different question, but the options `answerdelayed` etc. could help

Comment: thanks again. Bear with me - These questions are not really exercises, so what if I wanted to remove the text "Exercise 1" in the PDF document. Perhaps replace it with "Set 1" or something similar.

Comment: @Htown: `\renewcommand{\ExerciseName}{Set}` in the preamble, I assume.

Comment: Thanks again Christian. Suppose I want to remove the term "Exercise" completely. How would you change the command?    Second, you seem to suggest that nested enumerates are not the best way to handle such question sets. What is a better, perhaps more efficient alternative?

Comment: @Htown: The nesting issue isn't no more a problem since we've detected that a `\end{enumerate}` was missing. However, the advantages of `exercise` isn't use here at all: Keep a question (`Exercise`) in a an `Exercise` environment and an Answer in an `Answer` environment and it can be decided later on if the Exercises are shown, or append the answers at the end. Your're using `\textbf{Answer:}` and this will be always there. I am also not sure about the Explanation part -- is this meant for your students as some kind of hints? Where should it go to?

Answer (score 0):

Similar, one can use for the `exam` package

```
\usepackage{alphalph}
\renewcommand{\thepartno}{\alphalph{\value{partno}}}
```

where partno is the counter number.