# Enumerate with alpha counters like 'aa', 'ab' etc

Tags: enumerate, counters

When having a list like:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\RequirePackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*,start=25]
\item an item
\item an item
\item an item
\item an item
\item an item
\item an item
\item an item
\item an item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

we get the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Counter too large.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.23 \item a
            n item
```

due to the fact that the counter exceeds 26.

When having e.g. HTML the numbering would be like: `y`, `z`, `aa`, `ab`, `ac`, `ad` or at least wrap around back to `a`?

Does something like this exist in LaTeX as well?

Comment: The relevant duplicate is [Numbering exceeding the 26 letter alphabet](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/103496)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a go at it (tomorrow)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adapting one of the answers from here: [Counter too large error with \item](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269553/counter-too-large-error-with-item/)

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\RequirePackage{enumitem,alphalph}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\AlphAlphFmt}[1]{\@alphfmt{#1}}  % Define the \alphalph wrapper for enumitem 
\newcommand{\@alphfmt}[1]{\alphalph{\value{#1}}}  % Internal representation 
\AddEnumerateCounter{\alphalphFmt}{\@alphfmt}{aaa} % Register this new format
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label={(\AlphAlphFmt*)},start=25]
\item an item
\item an item
\item an item
\item an item
\item an item
\item an item
\item an item
\item an item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unrelated, but I'm curious: is there a reason for using `\RequirePackage` rather than `\usepackage`?

Comment: @chsk I just followed from the question of the OP.  However, if you are interested, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19919/whats-the-difference-between-requirepackage-and-usepackage

Comment: The reason I used `\RequirePackage` is that I cut and pasted it from a sty file.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes thanks, good to know!

Comment: Since we may need the equivalent in capital letters, I would suggest a slight modification in order to keep on with the difference between \alphalphFmt and \AlphAlphFmt :
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\alphalphFmt}[1]{\@alphfmt{#1}}  % Define the \alphalph wrapper for enumitem 
\newcommand{\@alphfmt}[1]{\alphalph{\value{#1}}}  % Internal representation 
\AddEnumerateCounter{\alphalphFmt}{\@alphfmt}{aaa} % Register this new format
\makeatother