# \begin{enumerate}[start = X] breaks after 27

Tags: errors, enumerate

I'm trying to continue an enumeration, so I'm initializing the environment as:

```
\begin{enumerate}[start = 27]
\item X 
\item Y
\item Z
\end{enumerate}
```

For which I get a big red error...
Funnily, it works just fine if I change the "start" counter to 24, which means it only cracks if the counter passes 27.

Even more weirdly, I use the same thing some hundreds lines of code above, and it works just fine.

I've been troubleshooting this for 2 hours already and I can't possible imagine what's wrong with it... Any ideas?

Comment: Please write a minimal working example. See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means.

Comment: Nevertheless a guess is that things are counted from a to z, and there's no 27th character after that.

Comment: If that is the case → [lists - Counter too large error with \item - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269553/counter-too-large-error-with-item) [numbering - Error: Counter too large! with \alph{cntr} and cntr>26 - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52599/error-counter-too-large-with-alphcntr-and-cntr26) [Subequation: Counter too large - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312456/subequation-counter-too-large)

Comment: You write, "I get a big red error." What does the error message say? Please be specific. Following up on one of the comments by @user202729 - would you by any chance have the instruction `\renewcommand\theenumi{\alph{enumi}}` in your document?

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was indeed in a special environment in which the counter was alphabetic so it crashed after 27. It got solved rather quick with adding [label = \arabic*.]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all!

It was an issue with an environment and the counter was changed to letters, therefore it crashed for > 26.

It was solved quite easily by changing the

```
\begin{enumerate}
```

to

```
\begin{enumerate}[label = \arabic*.]
```